# how to show my computer on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, partitioning

I am very new to ubuntu. I just installed the 13.10 and it seems I can't find the "my computer" (you know, that one with the partitions and stuff).

I am very sure this was asked a million times but I can't find an answer.
Please, help me ASAP. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you open Nautilus (the icon in the launcher that looks like a small filing cabinet).
This where you will find all your files and folders.

[image]

To the left there should be a heading named devices, it should show up there.

[image]

I am displaying here my 80gig partition with windows install on it.

Answer (score 0):

How are you?

So, What do you mean with My Computer? A place where do you find all your drives? or may be a place where you find all your files?

This must be with root and tree used in Linux, you can find some extrainfo right here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy.html#AEN23

May be is boring, but you can reach all your answere, just reading a little.

Take care.

Comment: About an hour ago I installed Ubuntu and before that I had on D: partition music, pictures and that kind of stuff. Now I can't seem to find the D: partiton anymore. That's what I meant with My Computer. I will read from the link that you posted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps for "Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS".

Go to Files >> Other Locations:

[image]

Click "Computer"

[image]

There you will see all the files/folders of your compouter:

[image]