# show Computer, or My Computer on Ubuntu MATE 20

Tags: ubuntu-mate, caja

How can Computer view be displayed in the Caja file manager in Ubuntu MATE 20.04.3?

the location is `computer:///`

`Nautilus` has it under Other Locations, but `caja` has no clear way to reach that location through the menus or buttons.

After unmounting a usb drive it accidentally came up:
[image]

And BTW, why aren't `total`, `available`, and `used` amounts shown in this view like in System Monitor? It seems a simple and useful feature.

These [other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344891/how-to-change-nautilus-to-show-file-system-instead-of-computer) [posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369177/how-to-show-my-computer-on-ubuntu-13-10) are too old to be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you already have a way to access *Computer* directly from Main Toolbar. There is special icon here:

> [image: Computer icon on toolbar]

Also you can access *Computer* from Caja using *Go* → *Computer*.
For quicker future access you can add the opened `computer:///` location to Bookmarks by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. And as the result it will be available in the Bookmarks section of Side Pane.

Also you can make this *Computer* icon visible on Desktop by `gsettings set org.mate.caja.desktop computer-icon-visible true` (or check Computer icon on the first tab of MATE Tweak).

If you select Traditional MATE Panel layout in MATE Tweak you will get Computer shortcut in the Places menu.

So I do not see any difficulties accessing `computer:///` location.

May be you are interested to precisely read Ubuntu MATE guide at https://guide.ubuntu-mate.org/ or some books from https://ubuntu-mate.org/shop/books/ to understand the system.

---

Then about disk sizes and spaces. This sounds like feature request. Please file it to Launchpad by `apport-bug caja` and then to Github at https://github.com/mate-desktop/caja/issues .

Comment: perfect. didn't even see the icon. great answer. I looked at the guide. Something might be in there but I searched for computer:/// and nothing showed up.